# CSS does not affect any HTML generated with JavaScript. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a javascript shopping cart HTML via javascript. When clicking on an item, it adds it to the cart. When trying to modify the javascript generated HTML, the CSS does not carry over. what is wrong?

```
//dropdown menu hidden
const cartDropdown = document.querySelector('.cart-dropDown-items');

//every single + symbol
const addToCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.addToCart');

//price of item
const foodPrices = document.querySelectorAll('.selection-row-title');

//name of item
const foodNames = document.querySelectorAll('.selection-row-foodName');

//weight of item
const foodWeights = document.querySelectorAll('.selection-row-weight');

for (let i=0; i<addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
    addToCartButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        const newItem = document.createElement('div');
        newItem.className = 'dropDown-item'
        newItem.innerHTML = `
                            <div class='dropDown-title dropDown-info'>
                                ${foodNames[i].textContent}
                            </div>
                            <div class='dropDown-amount dropDown-info'>
                                ${1}
                            </div>
                            <div class='dropDown-price dropDown-info'>
                                ${foodPrices[i].textContent}
                            </div>`;


        console.log(newItem)
        // if item currently exists in array, just update amount in checkout and increase count++
        if (items.includes(addToCartButtons[i].value)) {
        // if items does not exist in array, update dom with new item UI and count = 1 by default
        } else {
            items.push(addToCartButtons[i].value);
            cartDropdown.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newItem.textContent);
        }
    })
}
```

```
                <div class='cart-dropDown'>
                    <div class='cart-dropDown-header'>
                        <p>My Carts</p>
                        <p>Personal Cart</p>
                        <p class='cart-dropDown-close'>Close</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class='cart-dropDown-empty'></p>
                    <div class='cart-dropDown-items'>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
    //newItem DOM
.cart-dropDown-items {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.dropDown-title {

}

.dropDown-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:red ;
    color:red;
}
```

The CSS does not affect any of the classes created with createElement,innerHTML. What am i doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are just inserting the text content of the element, not the element itself, which is why none of your DOM gets added. Further, there is no need to use insertAdjacentHTML as `newItem` is already an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), which you can add using [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Replace

```
cartDropdown.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newItem.textContent);
```

with something like

```
cartDropdown.appendChild(newItem);
```